# Defective bluetooth in MBPr?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have had a MacBook Pro (Retina, Early 2015) since October 2015.  Recently, I started feeling that the Bluetooth hardware might be defective.  It started a few months ago where I started being bombarded by Bluetooth pairing requests from different kinds of devices (even though the bluetooth settings say that my device should not be discoverable).

I did a clean install when I first started to encounter the symptoms.  I tried to follow different workarounds and fixes.  I found one which included modifying the bluetooth `plist` file but none of them seemed to be effective.  What's driving me crazy is that other people who have Macs in my office do not face the same issue!

More recently, I started getting a "Bluetooth unavailable" message from time to time. My Bluetooth headphones also keep breaking up constantly while they are connected to the MBPr.

I think there might be a hardware issue with my laptop.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would install a clean os to the internal drive or an external drive. Since you have so many pairing requests, you should be able to rule out software issues quickly and for free or very low cost.

Then you would seek hardware repair or service.

Comment: I already did a clean install after I first started to encounter the symptoms (a few months back). I will try to do that again on an external drive and see if i will get these pairing requests when I boot from it.

Comment: Probably hardware then. Worth one more shot though if you don't mind, @adelejjeh. Also consider hardware includes reseating all the cables. Antenna could be dislodged or disconnected.